# How to test printer code without having POS Thermal printer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an aplication which have POS thermal printing.I have a sample code for Bluetooth Printer and Wifi Printer and USB printer.I already have a Epson USB 
printer and its working fine.but I dont have bluetooth and wifi printer so how to test that code?

Is any process available for testing that code is working or not?

Comment: Best would be to get a Bluetooth and WiFi printer. Interaction with real devices is hard to mock.

Comment: Is any solution?